# Jest React Native Component with promise

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I'm developing my first React Native App. I created a component which loads data from an API in componentDidMount:

```
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    data: null
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    let data = await this.getData();
    this.setState({data: data});
  }

  getData() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Api.get().then(data => {
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
        ....
    );
  }
}
```

The getData method is asynchronous. All works fine with this code.

Now I want to test my Component with jest. Here is my actual code:

```
test('Default test', () => {
  const p = Promise.resolve({
    ...
  });

  MyComponent.prototype.getData = jest.fn(() => {
    return p;
  });

  const wrapper = renderer.create(
    <MyComponent />
  );

  return p.then(() => {
    expect(wrapper.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

All works fine with this code. But, if I have multiple tests in my file, I get this error when I launch jest:

> Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.

How can I remove this error?